# Is it fine to call a webservice inside Application class?

Tags: android

I need a webservice to persist across Activities.

So as a scenario imagine `ActivityOne`, `ActivityTwo` and `ActivityThree`.

`ActivityOne` gets started, afterwards a button is clicked and `ActivityTwo` is launched. 
Now `ActivityOne` is in the background.

`ActivityTwo` calls a webservice but before the webservice returns, `ActivityTwo` was closed by the user (called `activity.finish()`) and `ActivityThree` was started.

I want the webservice response from the webservice called by `ActivityTwo` to be received by `ActivityThree`.

Basically, I need the response from the webservice, regardless of the activity.

I am thinking of calling the webservice inside `Application` class. Is that a good idea?

Comment: *probably* it will be OK, but it is not common practice *from what I know*. It is better to place the web staff into the service. Then you may use  Local Broadcasts to notify whoever is listening (all activities in your case) about that your service has received the result. Or more advanced - library like EventBus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kartikmalik Singletons "are Evil" and should be avoided as mush as possible today in 2018.

A clean and better solution is to use a Service (where the WebService lives in) and "bind()" to it from all Activities/Fragment by passing Listeners/Callback functions using a Local IPC technique.

Comment: Bound Services Documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services
Video Tutorial (other parts in bottom links of this page): https://cosmolearning.org/video-lectures/android-services-local-ipc-parts-1-2/

Comment: I did what you suggested here. That is to create a bound and also a started service. My webservice can now survive across activities and listen to its result by broadcast manager. My problem is that I need to start the service even when the app is in background. How could I do that?

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones if I answered to main thread question, why do you removed the "accepted" flag? Now you have a Service that persist between activities and the main purpose of this thread was achieved. Now you're asking for a complete different answer, so a new Question should be opened.
However you need some Event/Trigger to start the Service like an Alarm (that executes code at some specific time), an Hardware Event (when the device is unlocked or the screen turns on), etc...and only you know the answer of WHEN launch the Service.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice. I must have accidentally clicked it.

Comment: My exact use case is this, I have a chain of webservice which could complete even when the app is currently in the background. When the completes another webservice must also be called which is the webservice inside the service. I could not do this because while the activity is at the background, the service is unbound and only bounded back when the app goes foreground again. I could open a new question if you like.

Comment: You just need a Context to execute the command "startService()", so you can start a Service from another Service. Binding a Service is used to interact with it (getting/setting data) but the Service can be started from wherever you have a Context.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a singleton class for your webservice call and store webservice response in that class. next time in your ActivityThree when you call webservice, you can check if response is already there then return response or you can make a call. it will remove your data lost in case of broadcast or event bus (like when you broadcast your response using broadcast receiver or event bus and in case your receiver is not registered then you will not receive your response).